# How to pass multipart file data to a web service

Tags: web-services, servlets, multipart

I wanna do something like this.

1.Uploading a file from a `jsp` in multipart

2.Calling a servlet

3.In dopost of that servlet i wanna call a `webservice` which takes all the params passed by jsp to servlet along with the multipart data.

```
dopost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response){

    webserviceMethod(request,response);

}
```

I'm stuck on third point where I can set all request params to `webservice` method. But I don't know how to pass multipart file data to that `websevice`. I failed to do so. How can i do that part??

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm#BABFGCHB)

Comment: thanks peeskillet. But doesn't help my requirement. My requirement is i need to pass the multipart file data (text/xml/excel etc) to a  web service params.

Comment: Did you not read it all? You can get all the [`javax.servlet.http.Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html)s from the request. Then you can get the `InputStream` from the part, as well as other details. You're not going to get it as `.txt` file as it's coming in from a stream. You would need to whatever conversions you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at that jquery plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I'm also using this in my Application together with a java servlet:

```
 uploadImage: function (e) {
        var self = this;
        self.ignoreDrag(e);
        if ($('#feed_imageUploader').find('input').hasClass('error')) {
            return;
        }
        //cant put this in an model - ajaxSubmit has no done callback
        $('#img_uploaded h1').text(polyglot.t('iview.loading'));
        $('#feed_imageUploader').ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#img_uploaded',
            type: "POST",
            url: path.apiPath + 'item.uploadImg/' + self.itemId + '/' + token,
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            success: function () {
                self.afterUploadImage();
            }
        });

    },
 afterUploadImage: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.changed = true;
        var xFactorItemImage = 0;
        var yFactorItemImage = 0;
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10100000);
        $('#img_uploaded').html("<img src=\"" + path.tempImage + userId + "_" + self.itemId + ".jpg?id=" + randomnumber + "\" style=\"display:none\" id=\"cropPhoto_uploaded\">");
        var theImage = new Image();
        var cropPhoto = $('#cropPhoto_uploaded');
        theImage.src = cropPhoto.attr("src");
        var widthPhoto = 0;
        var heightPhoto = 0;
        var NwidthPhoto = 0;
        var NheightPhoto = 0;
        $(theImage).load(function () {
            $('#img_uploaded h1').empty();
            $('#additemimage').hide();
            NwidthPhoto = theImage.width;
            NheightPhoto = theImage.height;
            cropPhoto.css({
                maxHeight: $('#img_uploaded').height() + 'px',
                maxWidth: $('#img_uploaded').width() + 'px'
            });
            cropPhoto.show();
            $('#addimage_upload').fadeIn(aSpeed.middle);
            widthPhoto = cropPhoto.width();
            heightPhoto = cropPhoto.height();
            xFactorItemImage = NwidthPhoto / widthPhoto;
            yFactorItemImage = NheightPhoto / heightPhoto;
            cropPhoto.Jcrop({
                setSelect: helper.getMiddleSelectionOfImage(widthPhoto, heightPhoto, widthPhoto, heightPhoto),
                bgOpacity: 0.3,
                onChange: showItemImageCoords,
                onSelect: showItemImageCoords
            });
        });

        function showItemImageCoords(c) {
            $('#x111').val(parseInt(xFactorItemImage * c.x));
            $('#y111').val(parseInt(yFactorItemImage * c.y));
            $('#x222').val(parseInt(xFactorItemImage * c.w));
            $('#y222').val(parseInt(yFactorItemImage * c.h));
        }
    },
```

And the servlet part:

```
public void UploadImage(HttpServletRequest request, String filename, String folder,String bucketname) {
    File file;
    PropertyReader mainconf = new PropertyReader();
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items ;
    mainconf.getProb("conf/MainConfig.properties");
    s3 s3=new s3();
    try {
        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        // Process the uploaded file items
        Iterator i = items.iterator();

        //Iterate through the items
        String finalPath = "";
        FileItem fi;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            fi = (FileItem) i.next();
            if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                // Get the uploaded file parameters               
                String your_os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                String workingDir = "images";
                finalPath = mainconf.read("imagePath");
                if (your_os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
                    finalPath = finalPath + workingDir + "\\" + folder + "\\";
                } else if (your_os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || your_os.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
                    finalPath = finalPath + workingDir + "/" + folder + "/";
                } else {
                    finalPath = finalPath + workingDir + "{others}" + folder + "{others}";
                }
                file = new File(finalPath + filename + ".jpg");
                fi.write(file);
                s3.writeFile(bucketname, file, filename+".jpg");
                file.delete();

            }
            break;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UploadItemImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fabian. Thanks in advance.seems i posted my question kinda misleading. let me make it clear. im uploading file(text/xml etc) from a jsp in multipart encrypted, from there im calling a servlet. In dopost of that servlet i need to pass that multipart data to a webservice .i can add the hidden parameters using annotatin @FormDataParam to that webservice. What i want is  to pass the multipart file data to webservice  inside servlet dopost() as i im getting the multipart file data in the request.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe it is also interesting for others why you wanna do this - maybe there is a simpler/better way ;)